# no MEDIA response when ask "play news"

Tags: media, google-assistant-sdk

I'm doing test google-assistant-sdk(python) on our Arm linux platform, use same credentials.json and same device-model-id on Raspberry, but have not same result with raspberry when test "play news" command. On raspberry, sdk will output

```
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {"text": "play news"}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {"is_error_response": false}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {"with_follow_on_turn": false}

ON_MEDIA_TRACK_LOAD:
{
  "metadata": {
    "album": "Reuters TV 5-minute briefing (U.S.)",
    "album_art": "http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/WA10gikNluFtl4dkyHvP3h42oPBqjROLOQDQg0r6NTWyYvXF5OFY-XounxWKanpfRLMsS_oStiFqyAc90O8459WVEDiSQ63TGhmtQqozEi5vgBj8tKBlmf6JO-dqJabzIiKh=s128",
    "title": "Reuters TV (U.S.)"
  },
  "track_type": 1
}
ON_MEDIA_TRACK_PLAY:
{
  "metadata": {
    "album": "Reuters TV 5-minute briefing (U.S.)",
    "album_art": "http://lh6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/WA10gikNluFtl4dkyHvP3h42oPBqjROLOQDQg0r6NTWyYvXF5OFY-XounxWKanpfRLMsS_oStiFqyAc90O8459WVEDiSQ63TGhmtQqozEi5vgBj8tKBlmf6JO-dqJabzIiKh=s128",
    "title": "Reuters TV (U.S.)"
  },
  "track_type": 1
}
```

But no ON_MEDIA_TRACK_LOAD and ON_MEDIA_TRACK_PLAY on my arm platform.
I use python 3.6.3 on my arm platform. and no error show after

```
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
ON_END_OF_UTTERANCE
ON_RECOGNIZING_SPEECH_FINISHED:
  {"text": "play news"}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {"is_error_response": false}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {"with_follow_on_turn": false}
```

it just no these MEDIA event output, it seems like sdk can't process this MEDIA event on my arm platform, but no error and other things to check. Do anyone can give me some suggest? thanks! 
BTW, When I test "play music" on raspberry, and get response "Sorry, I can't do that on this device." is it right? I use google_assistant_library-1.0.0 to test, and it support to play news and music in its release note, but only "play news" seems to work on raspberry?

Comment: The [google-assistant-sdk reference](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/library/python/#google.assistant.library.event.EventType) show that ON_NO_RESPONSE event will be sent if no voice response, but no this event received, so voice response should send to sdk, but sdk didn't process it.